# Gödel encoding - Part I

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, encoding, ragged-list

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226292/g%C3%B6del-numbering-of-a-string) but different.

[Part II](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260178/g%C3%B6del-encoding-part-ii-decoding)

Taken from the book:  Marvin Minsky 1967 – Computation:
Finite and Infinite Machines, chapter 14.

#### Background

As the Gödel proved, it is possible to encode with *a unique positive integer* not just any string
but any *list structure*, with any level of nesting.

Procedure of encoding \$G(x)\$ is defined inductively:

1. If \$x\$ is a number, \$G(x) = 2^x\$
2. If \$x\$ is a list \$[n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3, …]\$, \$G(x) = 3^{G(n_0)} \cdot 5^{G(n_1)} \cdot 7^{G(n_2)} \cdot 11^{G(n_3)} \cdot...\$
   Bases are *consecutive primes*.

#### Examples:

`[0] → 3`

`[[0]] →` \$3^3 =\$ `27`

`[1, 2, 3] →`  \$3^{2^1} \cdot 5^{2^2} \cdot 7^{2^3} = \$
`32427005625`

`[[0, 1], 1] →` \$3^{3^{2^0} \cdot 5^{2^1}} \cdot 5^{2^1} = \$
`15206669692833942727992099815471532675`

#### Task

Create a program that encoding (in this way) any given (possibly ragged) list to integer number.
This is `code-golf`, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Input

Valid non-empty list.
**UPD**
Some considerations regarding *empty lists* are given [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260088/114511).

You may assume:

- There are no empty sublists
- Structure is not broken (all parentheses are paired)
- List contains only non-negative integers

#### Output

Positive integer obtained by the specified algorithm

#### Note

Numbers can be very large, be careful! Your code *must be correct in principle*,
but it is acceptable that it cannot print some number.
However, all test cases are checked for TIO with Mathematica program and work correctly.

#### Test cases

```
[0,0,0,0,0] → 15015
[1, 1, 1] → 11025
[[1], [1]] → 38443359375
[0, [[0]], 0] → 156462192535400390625
[[[0], 0], 0] → 128925668357571406980580744739545891609191243761536322527975268535
```

Comment: Wouldn't an empty list just be encoded as `1`? Ah, that would be the same as the encoding of the number `0`.

Comment: I upvoted just for "the Gödel"

Comment: @Stef I dont know what you mean but I upvoted (ofc because the question is good) but also! it does remind me of Kurt Godel (which, has some related to this question right? maybe not sure) anyway, have a great day on both of you ^^

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann  Thank you for interesting idea, I made some updates

Comment: @WilliamMartens Yes, Kurt Gödel's relationship to this question is that he came up with Gödel encoding.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, Thanks for replying! `:)`

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11 10 9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)! (Use of a dyadic chain in place of a monadic compound link avoiding the need for argument manipulation with `` ` ``.)

```
ß€Żð%¡ÆẸ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a ragged list of non-negative integers and yields its Gödel encoding.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EdNa47uPrxB9dDCw20Pd@34//9/dLSBjoJhLAgDAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EdNa47uPrxB9dDCw20Pd@34f7gdKPL/f3S0QawOlwKIAtOGOgpGOgrGUDEdBcNYMIbIGMLY0SBhIAHmAFVBtCtAjQIZqQDFXLEA).

#### How?

```
ß€Żð%¡ÆẸ - Link: non-empty list OR number, X
     ¡   - repeat...
    %    -   ...number of times: (X) modulo (X)
                                 positive ints -> 0
                                 zero -> nan*
                                 non-empty lists -> non-empty lists*
                                 * truthy non-integers are treated by ¡ as 1
   ð     -   ...action: the dyadic chain - f(X, X):
 €       -              for each E in X:
ß        -                call this Link with X=E
  Ż      -              prefix with a zero (if X=zero we get [0])
     ÆẸ  - recompose from prime exponent list
              e.g.:
                    [0,4,0,2] -> 3^4 × 7^2 = 3969
                          [0] -> 2^0 = 1
                            n -> 2^n (non-list n treated as [n])
```

Comment: [8 with `ð`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EdNa47uPrxB9dDCw20Pd@34f7gdKPL/f3S0QawOlwKIAtOGOgpGOgrGUDEdBcNYMIbIGMLY0SBhIAHmAFVBtCtAjQIZqQDFXLEA)

Comment: Pesky `\`` :) thanks @UnrelatedString

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 24 bytes

```
;2^₍|↰ᵐGl~lℕ₃ᵐṗᵐ≠≜;Gz^ᵐ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39oo7lFTb82jtg0Pt05wz6nLedQy9VFTM5DzcOd0IPmoc8GjzjnW7lVxQM7h6f//R0dHG8TqgNH/KAA)

Surely there are shorter ways to generate a list of primes…

Brachylog is based on SWI-Prolog and can deal with [arbitrarily large integers](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39oo7lFTb82jtg0Pt05wz6nLedQy9VFTM5DzcOd0IPmoc8GjzjnW7lVxQM7h6f//R0dHG8bqGIDQ/ygA), but this will quickly run out of memory for even simple lists.

#### Explanation

```
;2^₍                       Output = 2^Input
    |                      Or (if the input is not an integer)
     ↰ᵐG                   Recursive call of this predicate for all elements of the Input; call the result G
       Gl~l                Take a list with as many elements as G
           ℕ₃ᵐṗᵐ≠≜         It must be a list of primes greater than 3 and all different (it always unifies with increasing magnitudes)
                   ;Gz     Zip with G
                      ^ᵐ   Map power
                        ×  Multiply
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), `A` <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 11 bytes

@AndrovT cool result:

```
Eλ-[żǎ$vxeΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiRc67LVvFvMeOJHZ4Zc6gIiwiIiwiWzEsIDEsIDFdXG5bWzFdLCBbMV1dXG5bMCwgW1swXV0sIDBdXG5bW1swXSwgMF0sIDBdIl0=)

Unfortunately, can't explain in detail.
Hope one of Vyxal' experts helps...

My old version, maybe useful for beginners in Vyxal:

```
ƛIȧ[:L›ÞpŻ$vx¨£e|E]fΠ
```

Every input must be list of lists, so first test case should be `[[1, 1, 1]]` etc.

-2 bytes thanks @emanresu (Vyxal chat)

```
ƛ                       #Begin lambda map 
 Iȧ                     #Condition for If: is it list?
     [                  #Begin If
      :L›               #If list - get length and add 1
         ÞpŻ            #Get slice of given length from infinite  list of primes
            $           #Swap
             vx         #Recursively apply to list
               ¨£e      #Zip and reduce pairs with exponentiation
                  |     #Else
                   E    #If number - two power
                    ]   #End If and lambda map,
                     fΠ #Flatten and reduce by product
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixptJyKdbOkzigLrDnnDFuyR2eMKowqNlfEVdZs6gIiwiIiwiW1sxLCAxLCAxXV1cbltbWzFdLCBbMV1dXVxuW1swLCBbWzBdXSwgMF1dXG5bW1tbMF0sIDBdLCAwXV0iXQ==)

Comment: [11](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiRc67LVvFvMeOJHZ4Zc6gIiwiIiwiWzEsIDEsIDFdXG5bWzFdLCBbMV1dXG5bMCwgW1swXV0sIDBdXG5bW1swXSwgMF0sIDBdIl0=)

Comment: @AndrovT Cool, thanks! You should post your own answer!
Or, please explain, how `Π` works correct without closed `]` ?

Comment: there's no need to close structures in vyxal

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>103</s> <s>102</s> 98 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte, and then -4 more, both thanks to pajonk*

```r
`?`=\(x,p=3)`if`(sum(!p%%1:p)>2,x?p+1,`if`(is.list(x),`if`(length(x),(x[-1]?p+1)*p^?el(x),1),2^x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_RasIwFIbvfQplCDkzjpwTkzSDrpd9CJ2Ugc5CN8JaIe-ymyrsfXbr22iSSjdykfN_5-RL8n366s9l_nPs9svs8lYVVb5hnrtcQlXvK9YeP9jMzef47OCFuC_cAnns1O1TU7cd85Bys_t87w4hMr9e4muYhEe3LXZNgAicth5guOm3ZAKmD1OclAxDQbci-gQXEDtqJBiJGUnM8h7vLHrMH1Fag06MRuTEZXLQiowQSpP6bwsPxuEkCa211ZYyKe1tnoy1JKzNUK0MKknaqPSvvk_7FQ)

Comment: You've got an unnecessary newline at the end, I think.

Comment: @pajonk - Oh, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: Another -1: `x[[1]]`->`el(x)`

Comment: [98 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_RasIwFIbvfQplCDkzjpwTkzSDrpd9CJ2Ugc5CN8JaIe-ymyrsfXbr22iSSjdykfN_5-RL8n366s9l_nPs9svs8lYVVb5hnrtcQlXvK9YeP9jMzef47OCFuC_cAnns1O1TU7cd85Bys_t87w4hMr9e4muYhEe3LXZNgAicth5guOm3ZAKmD1OclAxDQbci-gQXEDtqJBiJGUnM8h7vLHrMH1Fag06MRuTEZXLQiowQSpP6bwsPxuEkCa211ZYyKe1tnoy1JKzNUK0MKknaqPSvvk_7FQ) by renaming the recurrence function to `?`.

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES13), 82 bytes

Expects a ragged list of Bigints. Returns a Bigint.

```javascript
f=(a,k=2n,t=1n)=>a.at?a.map(a=v=>(g=d=>k%d--?g(d):d)(k++)?a(v):t*=k**f(v))&&t:k**a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZJNTsMwEIUllqw4QjZUdn_tsWfsqeT2DmwRC4s0XaQkSIRehk0XcCg4DU6iVmoaSx558d43z6P5-q7qfHc6_Xw2xcL_PhVBxHkZoJo3QVcybOIyNtu4fIvvIoZj2Ih9yMOmfMwXi-1e5HKdS1HOZnIbxVGum2kop9MiPeVk0qzTO_bkv7uH17r6qA-75aHei0I8q-pFymx4VqvM3A-UrfRWm5TghlJdzbOUPTNX8BYKFpxSSIAj-Hmmq5euXFzJoxEUETExeGM4AcAxg2L2Gq3TaIDcDa6lXd8W2uGUvlHrrvd16765ViNRu5htHX7PW2sMshnP04_wnOXyPbIEmgENWqUMq7HhtM7OOHSDT04ib9Ch01YRe4VeOWudYbToWZNizRqscZSGRQYA0wQdAvnUs1-M8-r9Aw)

Or [79 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN_3TbDUSdbJtjXRKbA01be0S9RJL7BP1chMLNBJty2ztNNJtU2ztslVTdHXt0zVSNK1SNDWytbU17RM1yjStSrRss7W00oBMzZoSKyAzEWrsnOT8vOL8nFS9nPx0jTSNaINYTU0FZKCvr2DMhaYIqApVGVCRkTm6KgMdBQQCqQeqMjQ1MDRFV2ioowBCCCNBCg0NjEwhboQFAQA) without Bigints.

Comment: So we can use `BigInt()` in JS just adding `n` suffix?

Comment: @lesobrod Basically yes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 66 bytes

```arturo
f:$[x][(block? x)?[p:3∏map x=>[p^f&until->prime? p->'p+2]]->2^x]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?bPDONo)

```
f:$[x][                       ; a function f taking an argument x
    (block? x)?[              ; is x a block? then...
        p:3                   ; assign 3 to p
        ∏                     ; product
        map x=>[              ; map over x, assign current elt to &
            p^f&              ; p raised to the Gödel encoding of the current elt
            until->prime? p-> ; until p is prime...
                'p+2          ; add 2 to p via in-place modification
        ]                     ; end map
    ]                         ; end the 'true' part of the ternary
    ->2^x                     ; ...otherwise, if x isn't a block, take 2^x
]                             ; end function
```

Comment: Interesting fresh and bright language!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 103 bytes

```python
g=lambda n,k=1,m=1:m%k>n or-~g(n,k+1,m*k)
f=lambda l,p=3:l*0==0and 2**l or p**f(l[0])*f(l[1:]or 0,g(p))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY309NtcxJzk1ISFfJ0sm0NdXJtDa1yVbPt8hTyi3Tr0jWAotpAUa1sTa40mMocnQJbY6scLQNbW4PEvBQFIy2tHKByhQItrTSNnGiDWE0wbWgVCxQ00EnXKNDUhFrnXFCUmVeikaYBUqXJBecBuSh8Qx0jHWM0FTqGsUAEMwrmAwA)

Method for calculating next prime is shamelessly adapted from [Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108539/113573).

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 118 bytes

Modified from [@Dominic van Essen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260041/110802)

---

Golfed version, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7PTsMwDAbwO08xbUKKmSfFzpIsh3BBqG/ApfsjhMaUw0ZUuqkI8ezF0K4UOaefP31Ofq7S4pDbtlAN5mggfqZX9X4@qhQJM6p8myBGDfeMv5E5AUqi/sh71chmWu@eHh@mPzaT9VZCJW3grlCX/Uv9VokuCBM2ZZqLdwXyeNsAfLW5SqdaFUoDTNbrCd1cgTrgAUqNetOn7FipVz/W3swfifXI/l9pN0O1HrcTMpprFy/Za20d23Gr3B@@QJa1cy64wCtjguTZh8A6hBXZpSdr2HnbfgM)

```
G(x,p=3)={if(sum(i=1,p,(p%i)==0)>2,G(x,p+1),if(type(x)=="t_VEC",if(#x,p^G(x[1])*G(vector(#x-1,i,x[i+1]),p+1),1),2^x))}
```

Ungolfed version

```
G(x, p = 3) =
{
  if (sum(i = 1, p, (p % i) == 0) > 2,
    G(x, p + 1),
    if (type(x) == "t_VEC",
      if (#x,
        p^G(x[1]) * G(vector(#x - 1, i, x[i + 1]), p + 1),
        1
      ),
      2^x
    )
  )
}


print(G(0)) \\ 1
print(G(1)) \\ 2
print(G([0,0])) \\ 15
print(G([0,1])) \\ 75
print(G([0])) \\ 3
print(G([[0]])) \\ 27
print(G([0,0,0,0,0])) \\ 15015
print(G([1,2,3])) \\ 32427005625
print(G([[0,1],1])) \\ 15206669692833942727992099815471532675
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```
!x::Int=2^x
!(x,p=2)=prod(i->(while(p+=1).%(2:p-1)∋0end;p^!i),x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZHLSsNQEEBxm69IECHBtMzjzn1Urgt3fkOoILRipMTQphhwrQjduXXTTT9Kl_0Sb5O0lGEGZpg58_rZvawX5eN2u1s3TyP7e5e0k8l91Xh6aKMkbfPaU-br5essLUe36dtzuZin9bXHbHyV0qQeYbb_2sC8mt3UD0mZ5W3Wk_4u3pv5qlnFvogKmObx5f7zO-aoCM7JY08mKjCPKY_5FCXcbz6EKFhD7JkUGQDRJIfqPMZprwODoEvvi9CjEGitnXZkmV2oJeMcgXMWRRkUJm0CCfJBjiQUQOmmwTM-InR9D4FgTm2tUsziuEfFw1pnMK00oSNhUQDsoB-_O0WvQyLZkKS1ZTFiUIF2FsSCUcqwEyXWoQaHDkmx0WF8zUQSdjJC2gZ8NI3qZVk1i2qcjpPu6MMPjl_9Bw)

-2 bytes by MarcMush.

Doesn't use prime built-ins, which are not in Base anyway. Feels a bit weird to include a type annotation while golfing in a language that doesn't require it, but it looks like a decent way to disambiguate between numbers and lists.

Note that this will only produce correct output within Int64. At the expense of 5 bytes, we can add a `big(...)` wrapper to get a version that processes all test cases as desired:

### [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```
!x::Int=big(2)^x
!(x,p=2)=prod(i->(while(p+=1).%(2:p-1)∋0end;p^!i),x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZHLSsNQEEBxm69IECHBtMzjzn1UrlvxG0oLSqtGSgxtigHXitCdWzfd9KN02S_xNomlDDMww8yZ1_fueb0o7rbb3bp-GNifm6QZjW7L2t8Xjyll0yZK0iavPGW-Wr7M0mJwnb4-FYt5Wl16zIYXKY2qAWb7zw3My9lVNU2KLG-yDvd79lbPV_Uq9uNoDJM8Pt9_fMUcjYNz9NiTicaYx5THfIwS7jfvQhSsIfZMigyAaJJDdR7jpNOeQdCmd0XoUQi01k47sswu1JJxjsA5i6IMCpM2gQR5L_8kFEBpp8ETPiK0fQ-BYI5trVLM4rhDxf1aJzCtNKEjYVEA7KAbvz1Fp30i2ZCktWUxYlCBdhbEglHKsBMl1qEGhw5JsdFhfM1EEnYyQtoGfDSJqmVR1otymA6T9uj9D_5f-wc)

Comment: Kirill L. in fact program could accept single numbers. This is not quite clear point, but you can exclude special detection for numbers

Comment: @lesobrod Thanks, I've updated the answer to use the shorter version as the "default" one.

Comment: I didn't try it but `prod(f,x)` might be shorter than `prod(x.|>f)`?

Comment: @MarcMush It works indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
o"Ddië®δ.VāØsmP"©.V
```

Also works for loose integer inputs, instead of just (ragged) lists.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/X8klJfPw6kPrzm3RCzvSeHhGcW6A0qGVemH//0dHG@gYxgIRAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/fCWXlMzDqw@tO7dFL@xI4@EZxbkBSodW6oX91/kfbaCjEG0QCySAJIgy1DHSMYbwdQxjQQgkZghhRANJIAYxDXQgOiB6QUaAUSwA).

**Explanation:**

Recursive functions are always so verbose in 05AB1E.. :/

```python
o            # Take 2 to the power each inner-most integer of the (implicit) input
 "..."       # Push the recursive string explained below
      ©      # Store it in variable `®`
       .V    # Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)

D            # Duplicate the current list
 di          # If it's a single integer:
             #  (do nothing, simply keep it as is)
  ë          # Else (it's a list instead):
    δ        #  Map over each inner item:
   ® .V      #   Do a recursive call
       ā     #  Then push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
        Ø    #  Map index each to the 0-based prime: [3,5,7,...]
         s   #  Swap the two lists on the stack
          m  #  Take the primes to the power of the values
           P #  Take the product of this list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 67 bytes

```
≔Ｘ²Ａθ⊞υθＦυＦΦι⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκＦ⮌υ«≔¹η≔²ζＦι«≦⊕ζＷ¬⬤…²ζ﹪ζμ≦⊕ζ≧×Ｘζ⊟⁺⟦⁰⟧κη»⊞ιη»Ｉ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNa8MwDIbPya/QUQYPtl57KoNBDy0h9FZ6MKkXmzp26o8WMvrbMzt2dpzBWELvI@l1J5jtDFPzvHNO9hob8@QWNxT2egweCaFwJ9u6CU5gyPG3sYCBwPJ@SeUjICk0Kjg8XyjcCCGwArcVaPmDW8cjSOCnrsq4DwoiKtY0zp1SuhByEVYHNpbqXneWD1x7fi266imk4oBH43GnFLZM9zx3oXAw16AMThQGklb6t9FfsZW98HiSA3fR0/IbUwpGzAbfi8Oy@KuuFqsy56@6sVJ7/GTOY4LuUbqd53M8icz3Mr891C8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｘ²Ａθ
```

Vectorised raise `2` to the power of the input.

```
⊞υθＦυＦΦι⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκＦ⮌υ«
```

Extract all of the sublists and loop over them in reverse.

```
≔¹η≔²ζ
```

Start with a product of `1` and a last prime of `2`.

```
Ｆι«
```

Loop over the elements of the list.

```
≦⊕ζＷ¬⬤…²ζ﹪ζμ≦⊕ζ
```

Get the next prime number by trial division (1 byte shorter than Wilson's theorem).

```
≧×Ｘζ⊟⁺⟦⁰⟧κη»
```

Multiply the product by the prime power of the next list element (but if that's a list, then use its last element, as that's where we put the value on a previous loop iteration).

```
⊞ιη
```

Save the resulting value to the sublist.

```
»Ｉ⊟θ
```

Output the resulting value of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
L?sIb^2b*F^V.fP_Zlb3yMb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38e@2DMpzihJyy0uTC8tID4qJ8m40jfpf@X/6Ohog1gdBQgGAA)

Defines an encoding function `y(b)`.

#### Explanation

```
L                          # define y(b)
 ?sIb                      # if b is invariant under s: (sums for list, int for int)
     ^2b                   #   2 ^ b
                           # else:
                    yMb    #   apply y to each element of b
            .fP_Zlb3       #   generate a list of len(b) primes starting with 3
          ^V               #   vectorized exponentiation
        *F                 #   fold over multiplication
```

Comment: woah. great ! respect

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 37 bytes

```
1##&@@(i=1;Prime@++i^#&/@#)&//@(2^#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b731BZWc3BQSPT1tA6oCgzN9VBWzszTllN30FZU01f30HDKA7I@A@UyiuJVta1S3NQjlWrC05OzKur5qo2qNXhqgaSIMpQx0jHGMLXMawFIS6gAh0ohKgwBAtXVwNJIAYxDXQg@iEmgQwEI67a/wA)

```
                               (2^#)    numbers: x -> 2^x
                            //@         lists:
1##&@@(                /@#)               product of
       i=1;Prime@++i^#&                     prime(n+1)^x_n
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>32</sup> 30 bytes

```
*/@(p:@#\^$:&>)`(2^x:)@.(0=L.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfQdNAqsHJRj4lSs1Ow0EzSM4iqsNB30NAxsffQ0/2typSZn5CukKdjYGMCYhtZG1sYwjoaBtaGmtSHXfwA)

*-2 thanks to att*

Comment: I think you can `p:@#\ `

Comment: Yep, and that change allows me to save another byte too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.lists math.unicode`, 83 bytes

```factor
: g ( a -- n ) dup real? [ 2^ ] [ [ lprimes cdr lnth swap g ^ ] map-index Π ] if ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49DsIwDIV3TvFGGFoVRhgYEQsLYqpAilIXIlI3JKkAVdyFE3GlkjYgkCX/fO/Zcimkr2232643qznOZJk0KuFPcHRpiCW5YUwbVrIuCMaS93djFfsolA1Lr2r@@IJSkUu1ct4h5gXWmzmOtS67UDCGQJKAMUHRGFgSeokcswP2oeTQ8QRkYaG5/@QqTNjr9UqYRHFBN7yeYVQlFl2L6RCP4ElHLdqhj/nLMvQ8G0j254ws@9HuDQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 147 bytes

```powershell
$f={$r,$p=1,2
$args|%{do{$p++;for($u,$k=1,0;++$u-$p){$k+=!($p%$u)}}while($k)$r=$r*($b=[bigint])::Pow($p,(&($f,{$b::Pow(2,$_)})[$_-is[int]]@_))}
$r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJbb9owFH7nV3jotIqHI/kSO3GrSJnY9rCXVeveEEJATWFQnDnJ2JTmtzOHFAbDShzpfOe7HMe53RlXLM1mE86tM/s9LNIaHIE8ZYT3YOqei9eb@snWkA8G9wvrAqgIrD1K7wcDqELIcQ3rQfougPwGKtw0u@VqYwJYY3ApuPcBzNLRbPW82pZjfHf3YHe@kwS3ASxIDbOuwglMcINHMAlXxahtHWcTjJseuGafBT3kF0FZkAUUE9QXfXxWaneK2zqPLwBGECdIHBg84jGlUnF50eKZBDHcvX0mOVVKaaV5IoT2FB5rzanWCZNRzKTgKr4U8PR/T6dBmfw/BjsaMHoVoAXa/RAziSIhpBbXLmdzvvmoSHGmuRQyolRoej1bd1z0ROGJb1cqETKWMYuo0gmVCY2jKBZaRjLRTFHNNOORiJUfVwnOpT@DWHKVeCOvj9Er@mzdp@l8GX6d/TDzEtUHU39Z3PQPQWB@575qnlCKYNJBZ6XjXfA/fuoKf1GOWBcdnCmqTekbb2GBsoPmARg9PA6rorQvnek461zb9VjN56YoWr@TUWh@HrVOfR9aMf9N37L6SYZ2@8u48rsNvxR2i8KhfcldqxV@NHm5RIye2N@6YC37TLfpNfu/)

Fun challenge!

Recursive function that expects the input list using splatting and returns a `[bigint]`

Please ignore the inconsistent output of the array in the tests result as PowerShell has a tendency to flatten them sometime.

### Explanation

This part updates `$p` to become the next prime after `$p`

```powershell
do{$p++;for($u,$k=1,0;++$u-$p){$k+=!($p%$u)}}while($k)
```

This part checks whether the current list item `$_` is a number or not
If it is a number, we take its power of two, otherwise, we do a recursive call.

```powershell
$r=$r*($b=[bigint])::Pow($p,(&($f,{$b::Pow(2,$_)})[$_-is[int]]@_))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 71 bytes

Of course, answering your own challenge is a bit ridiculous, but it is rather a supplement to not break the main post.
Thanks @PaŭloEbermann for the idea!
It seems we can account for *the empty lists*, naively but correctly, using the next encoding:

1. If \$x\$ is non-negative integer, \$G(x) = 2^{x+1}\$
2. If \$x\$ is an empty list, `[ ]`, \$G(x) = 2^0 = 1\$
3. If \$x\$ is a list, \$[n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3, …], 
   G(x) = 3^{G(n_0)} \cdot 5^{G(n_1)} \cdot 7^{G(n_2)} \cdot 11^{G(n_3)} \cdot...\$

Of course, this is a purely intuitive idea without proof. But I do not see contradictions at the moment.

So here is Mathematica program that encodes *any array-like structure* (with possible empty lists) with a unique positive integer.

```
Switch[#,{},1,{__},Times@@(Prime@Range[2,Length@#+1]^#0/@#),_,2^(#+1)]&
```

Some related test cases:

```
[] → 1
[[]] → 3
[[], 1, []] → 13125
[[], [0, []], 1] → 204721573027200065553188323974609375
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7g8syQ5I1pZp7pWx1CnOj6@VickMze12MFBI6AIyHAISsxLT4020vFJzUsvyXBQ1jaMjVM20HdQ1tSJ1zGK0wAKaMaq/QcqzitxSHOoBpqjUG0AxLVAhmHtfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 51 bytes

```
f(x)=if(x'===0,2^x,prod(i=1,#x,prime(i+1)^f(x[i])))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN43TNCo0bTOBpLqtra2BjlFchU5BUX6KRqatoY4yiJ2Zm6qRqW2oGQdUE50Zq6mpCdWaklhQkFOpkaiga6cAVJZXAmQqgThKCmkaiZqaOgrR0QY6UBgL5BnqKIAQiBkNJg1jQaQBWCGICVYFYkOYQDGoXTDnAgA)