# Gödel encoding - Part II (decoding)

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, encoding, ragged-list

[Part I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259960/g%C3%B6del-encoding-part-i)

Previous part was considered encoding of non-empty nested lists with a positive integer.

Reminding the coding procedure \$G(x)\$:

1. If \$x\$ is a number, \$G(x) = 2^x\$
2. If \$x\$ is a list \$[n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3, …]\$, \$G(x) = 3^{G(n_0)} \cdot 5^{G(n_1)} \cdot 7^{G(n_2)} \cdot 11^{G(n_3)} \cdot...\$
   Bases are *consecutive primes*.

The number *will be unique* (it can be proved, but you don’t have to do it).
So always there is *valid reverse procedure*:
determine an array-structure from a given number,
or verify that no structure exists for that number.
This is the task of this challenge.

#### Input

Positive integer (possibly very large)
**UPD**
I know that in CG does not approve strict validation of input.
But here *invalid in general* number means: negative, float, with typo etc.
You don’t have to check it out!
But figuring out if a number is *valid encoding* or not is part of the challenge.

#### Output **UPD**

*Very sorry I missed the important thing ((*
Single number (if it is suitable for the first part of the procedure, see test cases)
or
non-empty list of non-negative integers (possibly nested, without empty sub-lists) that is encoded with given number;
printed in any appropriate form: as pure array, string, json etc.
*OR*
any appropriate message (`[ ], None, -1` etc), if there is no decoding for this number.

#### Test cases

```
1 → 0
2 → 1
3 → [0]
4 → 2
5 → None
6 → None
7 → None
8 → 3
9 → [1]
10 → None
666 → None
729 → None
1024 → 10
1215 → None
3375 → [[0], [0]]
77777 → None
5859375 → [0, [1]]
666777666 → None
2210236875 → [3, 2, 1, 0]
7625597484987 → [[[0]]]
1111111111111111111111111111 → None
```

Comment: Suggested test cases: `729`, `1215`. I think they're both invalid.

Comment: Can malformed-but-varied outputs be given for malformed inputs, like a nested structure containing `-1` where the encoding is *immediately* malformed? (I assume not, but it's worth clarifying.)

Comment: @UnrelatedString, I also think not; if number is not valid, there is no _any_ corresponding structure for it, so output should be just a message. I think even empty array is not good

Comment: Is Gödel-encoding of lists (rather than strings) a generally-known transformation, or largely invented for this challenge?  I notice that the OEIS doesn't seem to have an entry for the sequence of integers that represent valid Gödel-encodings of lists (sequence starts 1,2,3,4,8,9,15,16,27,32,45,64,75,81, I think)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen,  I just steal idea from Minsky old book, mentioned in Part I. Encoding is described in the book directly, and decoding - as exercise.

Comment: And thank you for idea, I’ll try to make a proposal to OEIS, it'll be cool 8)

Comment: Since you've described the output as a _non-empty list of non-negative integers (possibly nested [...])_, I've assumed that something like `8` is an invalid input, although it could be also decoded to `3`, as assumed by @DominicvanEssen. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Arnauld, I’m very sorry I wasn’t paying attention ((
According to the book, single number is valid structure. Post is updated!  
The point is that we can code single number in many different ways, and for lists we need a special way. But it can also be used for numbers.

Comment: could 1 not be an empty list?

Comment: @user253751 situation with empty lists is not quite clear. Neither here nor in Part I we don't use them to avoid confusion. An example of their possible use is given here https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260088/114511

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 167 bytes

Expects a Bigint. Returns `-1` if the encoding is invalid.

This is probably longer than it should, but validating the encoding is costly (see below).

```javascript
n=>(e=h=(n,F=n>1&&n%2n?(n,k=3n,i=0n)=>n%k?i?[h(i),...k>n?[]:F(n,-~k)]:(g=d=>k%--d?g(d):e|=d<2)(k)?[]:F(n,-~k):F(n/k,k,-~i):n=>n%2n?e|=n>1:-~F(n/2n))=>o=F(n))(n)&&-e||o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNboMwEITvfQouQbZkCLb5Vw23HPsCiEMUSEIdraum6gnl1elagjZ1Sywh2fMtM2O/7j/318P78PYRgOn66agmUBXp1VkRYDsFFfd92Aio8aiVBDaoCKiqYKProW7OZKAsDENdQd205Q6ngpumbUlOqlOV3gRBV59IR8t@VN2zoETT@0G72Wqm8TDQEqwvZuEsBpfBzVIBFPOMwj2l@Pl@0I@jmQ4GrubShxdzIkfCEXrbrRc9/dbFrHNHj2ddOHo@69LReSSWX7ibIWfQRK1DioVwl6RpOrMXA70DM1GsQy54sk6lzBbaYB9mS7nZmV3rFkmeFHcuEbP1/@mPJg9vIQQ@mkzzHyvJPME8zrw/D5WlIkmKLM7jIs@@@9vu7fQF)

#### 111 bytes (for information only)

A large part of the code is dedicated to Gödel encoding validation. If we assume that the input is a valid encoding, then several sanity checks can be removed and we don't even have to include a primality test:

```javascript
f=(n,F=n>1&&n%2n?(n,k=3n,i=0n)=>n%k?[...i?[f(i)]:[],...k>n?[]:F(n,-~k)]:F(n/k,k,-~i):n=>n%2n?0:-~F(n/2n))=>F(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NboMwEITvfQpfEmHJgH9wMEiGW17C8iFKQ@Q6Wqqm6jGvTtcV9Me97c43s7Mvp4/T/fwWXt9LmJ8vyzLZAtjRwiD2e9hJGHGNVgELlgO1A@zi6KqqCqObikB97zzDNQ4wOt8f0V0@Iv2a6sgiboH2kHJ4i/flIwEJFE/hRJfzDPf5dqlu87WYCoGA1DXhT391ueoi05tVl5luVl1luuByi4i8Q63AcZ@RbiMiJ0q1eoOYYymce7TR3S8bZ@lObpISX1MH8@NTjEhGBCP/3mkPUuuubUzTmfa7PTX75RM)

Comment: Arnauld, Thanks for ideas about validation, post a bit updated

Comment: I think the output for '8' should be '3'...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Making sure that the top level structure is a list was actually costing me some extra bytes. Now updated according to the new rules.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>168</s> <s>149</s> <s>132</s> <s>117</s> 116 bytes

*Edits: -9 and -1 bytes thanks to pajonk (re-defining `if` as `[`, now no longer needed, and then function as `` `~` ``), -7 bytes by switching to `\` instead of `function`, and -35 more bytes by re-arranging.*

```r
`~`=\(x,p=2,y=0)`if`(!x%%p,`~`(x/p,p,y+1),`if`(p==2&x<2,y,c(if(sum(!p%%1:p)<3&p>2|y)list(~y[!y|p>2]),if(x>1)x~p+1)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVNLTsMwEF2w4xRuUSqPGETsND9Ud0PXXCBUCooSEQlSy3WkRKqy5ABs2QQkDgVLToJDdm2EUnUWtuyZN_Oen_z2rtqPlfgsdXYVfOm4icU9rVAKjrWwIc6zmE4qy5JoUrS6liixvmSAfxkpBJ9VC1OLCc0zui2f6URaFruRsHBmcsl3NTzlW02bOprUO3OxBjSF1ZJB1UjTCKCf_X12rlV9-6CTR7rViq5oCICpUhslsrJIdL4paApS5YWm02JTpFMAckF-Xl5JxNb7YM_zRsPvzGkf7_Px44fwjuO74_lH9hqJWQ5kMM7GtxnU0cVJHdzADY8SY2NnyJAjhsqpvnDObO54wTGEHCQcCUNiH5DyPe66oT8P5mEw_pmizrABs_6J40T3X6Jt-_0X)

Outputs the number or list whose Gödel encoding is the input.  Errors if no such number/list exists.

**Ungolfed code:**

```
D=function(x,p=2,y=0){
    if(!x%%p)D(x/p,p,y+1) else
    if(p==2&x<2)y else 
    c(if(is_prime(p)&p>2|y)list(D(y*(!y|p>2))),if(x>1)D(x,p+1))
}
is_prime=function(x)sum(!x%%1:x)<3
```

Comment: With so may `if`s first thing for me was to try assigning `if` to `[`. Looks like it does [save some bytes indeed](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZPPSsNAEMYP3nyKtBKZwRGzm-afmF7s2RdYApHSaKAmy3YLWR_AB_DqQT34UHr0SdwYitAGSekcFnbY3-z37ce-vKu3t4-1Ls7jz9dZWqyruS7rChqSqU8m9SgXeZqXRY7QXPHTkUHhEYwa1-UoAEy6rO84NIiuy1A8kskIVusHGEnbuJQ4tcdm7bgzhh0nfxsXkiSZrmlacA7LcqVhBgaRygKaKcMNiFlbncyvo2OtzPWtnt_DSisLJBZYKFWrP_kLlKqsNIyrulqMEZ0T5_vp2REs24bDMByM39jdNh_x4df38b4fBcP1Cy8jxy47Nhhnw8f0-mjroAlBHCR7mfGoDaQvESvl0Fw4Zx73w3gfQT45nBxGjrcjKgp5ECTRJJ4k8fBnEm1gPWH9U_uZ7r7E5gf_AA), even with all those extra `()`.

Comment: @pajonk - Yes, thanks.  I had a feeling that that might work, but didn't do it because I suspected (and still do...) that the enormous number of ```if```s might indicate that the code isn't very optimal, and could be more-elegantly written...  but so far I haven't figured-out how...  So ```[``` it is!

Comment: @pajonk - I finally got rid of enough ```if-else```s that the ```[``` substitution only breaks-even...

Comment: Great news, well done!

Comment: Also, [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVNLTsMwEF2w4xRuUSqPGETsND9Ud0PXXCBUCooSEQlSy3WkRKqy5ABs2QQkDgVLToJDdm2EUnUWtuyZN_Oen_z2rtqPlfgsdXYVfOm4icU9rVAKjrWwIc6zmE4qy5JoUrS6liixvmSAfxkpBJ9VC1OLCc0zui2f6URaFruRsHBmcsl3NTzlW02bOprUO3OxBjSF1ZJB1UjTCKCf_X12rlV9-6CTR7rViq5oCICpUhslsrJIdL4paApS5YWm02JTpFMAckF-Xl5JxNb7YM_zRsPvzGkf7_Px44fwjuO74_lH9hqJWQ5kMM7GtxnU0cVJHdzADY8SY2NnyJAjhsqpvnDObO54wTGEHCQcCUNiH5DyPe66oT8P5mEw_pmizrABs_6J40T3X6Jt-_0X) with another weird substitution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
λ1>[∆Ǐḣvx₌∨∧ßu›:A∧]‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+UCIsIiIsIs67MT5b4oiGx4/huKN2eOKCjOKIqOKIp8OfdeKAujpB4oinXeKAuSIsIiIsIjkgPT4gWzFdXG42NjYgPT4gLTFcbjcyOSA9PiAtMVxuMzM3NSA9PiBbWzBdLCBbMF1dXG4xMjE1ID0+IC0xXG43Nzc3NyA9PiAtMVxuNTg1OTM3NSA9PiBbMCwgWzFdXVxuNjY2Nzc3NjY2ID0+IC0xXG4yMjEwMjM2ODc1ID0+IFszLCAyLCAxLCAwXVxuNzYyNTU5NzQ4NDk4NyA9PiBbW1swXV1dXG4xMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExID0+IC0xIl0=)

Returns `-1` for invalid inputs. Times out on the last test case.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 101 bytes

```
n->iferr(g(n),e,x)
g(n)=if(n==2^q=logint(n,2),q,primes(1+#t=factor(n)~)[^1]-t[1,],0/0,apply(g,t[2,]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY5BTsMwEEX3nGJUNraYiHhSO87CvUiUIgvFkaXiuq4rwYYrcAA2kRDiTNwGJ-2av5n5M0_z5_Mn2uSfpjh_OTDfl-wq_TuGaufdmBKbWOA44iu_WzrjHQvG0P5kDsfJh8wCEscTxuRfxjMTD_fZOPucj6nQ77zfi6HKvcAB68cabYyHNzZh7gkHzm9hH9exhWoH5U45amGzmA04ZjlH6DsEpRRC07QSoV2EILXsVl9WZbACRKKmRukVUyRl1271ttMFF_-owFQyBAk53N6a52v9Aw)

Returns `x` for invalid inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ȯ6ÆEsß€Ḣ?ḢḊ?0
ÇŒṘ
```

A full-program that accepts a positive integer and either:

- prints the decoded value and exits with a code of `0`; or
- prints nothing to STDOUT and exits with a code of `1` (printing a traceback to STDERR).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EerPDba7Fh@c/alrzcMcieyB@uKPL3oDrcPvRSQ93zvj//7@5mZGpqaW5iYWJpYU5AA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##HU@7qsJAFOz3K4Ygei2EZJN9Iept/BJdMRJ2wSSFr8ZCwdLqdoK1YKt1EPyN@CO5ux44cGbOzMCs83nTFDovfrrYED2ZW/QMgtYvBkMEZKGzbAVdGnTed14dxnl1@exv9eM6cls/TqOQVMfXuX7@deBMdNgOsd3iGxQYi9xmZZFag5ktzTQgOzKzS6RIDSJQJJCIQpoghgLnHIIqxLFgiGjEIPyASaY85f4OehWlzhRz6UjBKWNKJDJRUvQxtfBt0Er9bXTT/AM) (in Zsh to catch the exit code).

#### How?

```
ȯ6ÆEsß€Ḣ?ḢḊ?0 - Helper Link: positive integer, N
ȯ6            - logical OR with 6 (when N=0 use 6 - this is so that recursive calls
                                   handle zeros in the ÆE result in a way that will
                                   produce the error we want)
  ÆE          - prime factorisation list (e.g. 56=2*2*2*7 -> [3,0,0,1])
           ?  - if...
          Ḋ   - ...condition: dequeue (i.e. is of length 2 or more)
        ?     - ...then: if...
       Ḣ      -          ...condition: remove and yield the head (exponent of 2)
    s       0 -          ...then (i.e. non-zero): split into chunks of length zero
                                                  (this will error out)
      €       -          ...else: for each (of the rest of the exponents):
     ß        -                     call this Link with that number
         Ḣ    - ...else: head (i.e. yield the power of two that N is)

ÇŒṘ - Main Link: positive integer, N
Ç   - call the helper Link, above
 ŒṘ - print a Python representation of the result
```

Comment: @lesobrod : this is 17 `UTF-8` chars but 32 bytes. Jelly requires `python` as a back-end interpreter instead of being standalone, so unless someone can prove they have already ported python to the single byte custom code page, it needs to be counted in `UTF-8` instead. If I follow the code page's mapping and send in byte `0xC1 :: \301` for `Ḋ` instead of `0x E1 0x B8 0x 8A :: \341\270\212 (utf8)`, perhaps I'm missing something, but from everything I've seen in the interpreter's source code …...

Comment: @lesobrod : …….. it lacks the capability to decode `UTF-8 invalid` bytes like `0xC1`, thus further weakening its claim it's cross-compatible w/ both `UTF-8` and its custom code page.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto The hex bytecode `f1 36 0d 45 73 15 0c c5 3f c5 c1 3f 30 7f 0e 13 cc` is the actual program and may be run with the `f` flag. See the [readme](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/README.md), the [code](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/__main__.py#L64), and the [codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: codepage only means jack when the underlying interpreter is also running in the same environment. please show proof you have ported python to execute directly over this codepage instead of in emulation mode over UTF-8, esp since the custom codepage has also remapped `0x0A` from `\n` in `ASCII/UTF-8` to `½`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto I am unsure what you are asserting, is there a [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/) you can point me to that covers this? If not then maybe you should post there for people in the community that may understand you better so things can be decided. (I do not know when an interpreter _wouldn't_ be "running in the same environment" as the program. Also, Jelly is not _mine_, I have contributed to it but really I just write code :p).

Comment: There's nothing being alleged. You count it in the custom code pages if Jelly has a stand alone binary interpreter itself not reliant on python, otherwise we can only count it on what python is capable of handling. Simple as that.

Comment: Where is the meta consensus on this? (That is what meta is _for_ after all.) Note that I'm not entirely sure _what_ the issue actually is -- I _think_ that you mean that because a program must be run as `python jelly ...` it must count using Python's code-page -- however, the code being executed is simply bytes in a file so I don't see the difference between bundling Python into a binary and running the program like that. Also note: I do not own the language, but it was written by a (ex) codegolf.stackexchange moderater in a way that met all criteria for a language for codegolf.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 100 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦Ｘ³Ｎ⟧Ｆυ«≔⊟ιθ¿﹪θ²«≔²η≔⟦⟧ζＷ⊖θ¿﹪θη«≦⊕η¿⬤…²η﹪ηλ⊞ζ⁰»«⊞ζ⊕⊟ζ≧÷ηθ»Ｆζ¿∧κ¬＆⊖κκ⊞ι⊖Ｌ↨κ²«≔⟦κ⟧κ⊞ικ⊞υκ»»⊟ι»⭆¹⊟§υ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFNj4IwEIbP@CvmOE26iavZ7METxouJGuIejQdWKm2orUKrGzb@dnYo4GoCIfP1zPsOB5mWB5vqpkl8JdFz2CX2Jkqcclias3cbf/qmkLE9m42OtgT0DH5HUVxVKjeY2DMqxuFC1UgdAdc289rihcOEhcahc8JBtk1DvNtzqEPiJpUWgAtxKMVJGCcyvNDsK032tGidnnvC0jwGBnaQEGuN29TkotvJoadIDpoRJjitOYzDyB2ErkTHHipP5OCwprHZy/KtyqUjBW6hrioTtKe/QXSnN9yp7izEJsOCw8Y6nCt3U5VoM89mC5JYsIcyxeG5uhImdxLnaSVazoT1Wv5VDwct9i1n9jCiXkM/hKSQnjCflMq4/idS7T7qEl@OPjmZxXcObTV2S5OJn5Yxbvc3zXT6@dG8XfUf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦Ｘ³Ｎ⟧
```

The main loop only works on lists of odd numbers, so fake it out by starting with a list of `3ⁿ`.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop over the input and any sublists that may be generated while processing it.

```
≔⊟ιθ
```

Get the value to turn into a list.

```
¿﹪θ²«
```

If it's odd, then:

```
≔²η≔⟦⟧ζ
```

Start finding prime factor multiplicities.

```
Ｗ⊖θ
```

Repeat until the all the factors have been found.

```
¿﹪θη«
```

If the current prime is not a factor, then:

```
≦⊕η
```

Try the next integer.

```
¿⬤…²η﹪ηλ
```

If this is a prime, then...

```
⊞ζ⁰
```

... start counting its multiplicity.

```
»«
```

Otherwise:

```
⊞ζ⊕⊟ζ
```

Increment the multiplicity.

```
≧÷ηθ
```

Divide the value by the prime.

```
»Ｆζ
```

Loop over the multiplicities.

```
¿∧κ¬＆⊖κκ
```

If this is a power of `2`, then...

```
⊞ι⊖Ｌ↨κ²«
```

... push its logarithm to the list, otherwise:

```
≔⟦κ⟧κ⊞ικ⊞υκ
```

... push the wrapped value to both the list and also the list of sublists to be processed.

```
»»⊟ι
```

Otherwise, crash the program, because the input is invalid.

```
»⭆¹⊟§υ⁰
```

Output the final value.

Since the above program has to find the logarithm to base `3` of `3ⁿ` the slow way, here's a slightly less slow 112 byte version which special-cases inputs of powers of `2` to avoid this:

```
Ｎθ¿＆θ⊖θ«⊞υ⟦θ⟧Ｆυ«≔⊟ιθ¿﹪θ²«≔²η≔⟦⟧ζＷ⊖θ¿﹪θη«≦⊕η¿⬤…²η﹪ηλ⊞ζ⁰»«⊞ζ⊕⊟ζ≧÷ηθ»Ｆζ¿∧κ¬＆⊖κκ⊞ι⊖Ｌ↨κ²«≔⟦κ⟧κ⊞ικ⊞υκ»»⊟ι»⭆¹§υ⁰»Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨θ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNa8IwGMfP8VM8xwQycA7ZRk91XoQp4o7iobOxCY2pbRIdHX72LumbVdihKc/bL///kz2Pin0WyapaqJM1K3v8ZgXOSTASB8AzYS5Cs1DFOKcwZ/uCHZkyzIWEEPgdobXVHFsK23znZtAhKwDbuoJCrUWi8Do7YUEoeCZCnrrMYiszT5w0kL53QoHXbV1iu6NQNpkLF5IBfhAB90DeAdEyOrWMheonenytI5QSbyKVsOZeCi2HU5DeXu2tpDBuZq7ApGYtvqsN4LXT0g0G9wI2IuHGqTBzcRYxc1d1y0BXf9Q7KxsnftMphVVmhrsfek6dzpT08sT9s3wylRiOZ5FmnjMhnZyB9G616c6Tgpsd8RDbPvY6/VdT1oVQpn1WX3aFJvVl3C9xvvEzhdAsVMx@PGTs266jwfBHpA3@T3fe6iZBVU3fpu8vr9Pq6Sz/AA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 32 bytes

```
L?sIlbslbCWneJCr8Pb.fP_ZleJ3yMhJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG5CgIxFAXQP5K85b6lspjKoDCdYCMERqYIIo5Nvj6e8xm/fc7r@bj0dvS23N9bXb6xttNrfT76VmXc9jrHJI5kmIXA4aTFMgqiuKpLQhFJVpKSWMWNICbMYE8HW0DwBw)

Defines a decoding function `y(b)` which returns the decoded list or throws a TypeError if the input is invalid.

#### Explanation

```
L                                   # define y(b)
 ?                                  # if
    lb                              # log base 2 of b
  sI                                # is an integer:
      slb                           #   return int(log(b))
                                    # otherwise
             J                      # assign J to
                 Pb                 #   the list of prime factors of b
               r8                   #   length encoded
              C                     #   and transposed
          W                         # if
            eJ                      # the last element of J
           n                        # is not equal to
                   .fP_ZleJ3        # the first length(eJ) primes (starting at 3):
         C                          #   apply transposition (this will result in a TypeError)
                                    # otherwise
                            yM      # apply y to every element of
                              hJ    # the first element of J
```